# Is there a way to inject MDB javadoc as its description?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, javadoc

In JavaEE6, [`MessageListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/MessageListener.html) are defined by the [`@MessageDriven`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/MessageDriven.html) annotation. This annotation defines a `documentation` element. My question is quite simple : is it possible to copy the class javadoc in this element (without copy/pasting it, obviously), as an example via a maven plugin or any kind of build-time scripting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into similar issues (trying to use javadoc like comments as JMX annotation values) and so far as I can tell, the answer is somewhere between **no** and **not very easily**. I suggest two avenues of research to implement this:

- [Paranamer](http://paranamer.codehaus.org/) is a library that can reference javadoc in order to determine the coded name of Java method parameters. While it does not support what you're looking for, it should be simple enough to modify the code to support this since the concept is the same.
- Reverse the dependency and implement a JavaDoc Doclet to extract the javadoc from the MDB @MessageDriven annotation rather than the other way around (since I assume you are simply trying to avoid duplication).